# barcode recognition with Zxing .net

Tags: c#, .net, barcode, zxing

I'm writing a windows service that reads barcodes (there will be only code39 type) from single page tiff and does something after decoding the barcodes.

The issue is on barcode recognition: it works less than 50% of the times.
I tested it with a consistend batch of tiff and compared the results with https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx that uses the original ZXing (Java).

My code use the sample provided here https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ but I believe barcode recognition can be improved, sadly I didn't found further code samples...

this is my code:

```
List<Document> risma = new List<Document>();

// create a barcode reader instance
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
string currentBarcode = "";

foreach (FileInfo scannedPage in inputScans)
                {
                    // load a bitmap
                    var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(scannedPage.FullName);
                    // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
                    var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
                    // first page of a new document
                    if (result != null && result.Text != Settings.Default.AttachmentBarcode)
                    {
                        currentBarcode = result.Text;
                        risma.Add(new Document(new Page(currentBarcode, scannedPage)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // checks for pages before the first recognized barcode
                        if (currentBarcode == "") continue;
                        // add remaining pages to current document
                        else risma.Last().AddPage(new Page(currentBarcode, scannedPage));
                    }
                }

// save documents to file
foreach (Document doc in risma) doc.MakeTiff();
```

My question is: is there a better way to decode a code39 barcode with Zxing.net?

---

I added the following after creating the BarcodeReader object.

```
// configure and create a barcode reader instance
                List<BarcodeFormat> codeFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
                codeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
                IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader()
                {
                    AutoRotate = true,
                    TryInverted = true,
                    Options =
                    {
                        PossibleFormats = codeFormats,
                        TryHarder = true,
                        ReturnCodabarStartEnd = true,
                        PureBarcode = false
                    }
                };
```

Now the recognition is really better. Don't know if there are other possibilities in Zxing .net, it would be nice anyway

Comment: You should set the option "reader.Options.TryHarder = true;".
Anyway, is it possible that you can send me some of your test files so that I can compare the .net version against java directly? You can reach me via email or the project homepage (https://github.com/micjahn and the old one http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you Michael. I found the option and set it at what, correct me if I'm wrong, are the maximum possible for recognition. I edited the question inserting the changes

Comment: Without sample images I can't help here any further

Comment: hey @refex just want to ask you that is your solution works fine, because for me it doesn't work at least for once?